# For a C++ unordered_map, how can I add a key-value pair if it's new, and apply a function to the value if it's key already exists?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

Given:

```
unordered_map<string, float> my_map
```

And a pair:

```
auto my_pair = make_pair("some_key", some_float);
```

How can I efficiently insert the pair into the map if `some_key` does not exist,
and if `some_key` does exist, automatically add `some_float` to the key's existing value?

My current solution (or lack thereof, surely there's a more elegant way to do it):

```
auto added = my_map.emplace(my_pair); 
if(!added.second) { // my_key already has an associated value
    auto &curr_value = *my_map.first; // pointer to the existing pair
    curr_value.second += my_pair.second; // add some_float
}
```

Comment: Although Benjamin's answer addresses your problem, if value initialization is not what you want, your solution is as short/elegant as it gets. You could write the last two lines into one, `added.first->second += my_pair.second;`, but not everyone would agree it improves readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my_map["some_key"] += some_float;
```

This will value initialize the float *(i.e. set it to 0.0f)* if it does not already exist.  And then it will add `some_float` to it (whether it existed or not).